# yii assign dynamic attributes after query

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a Yii query:

```
$criteria->select = 't.baniid,SUM(t.impression) AS impression, SUM(t.`unique`) AS `unique`, IFNULL((SELECT SUM(clicks) FROM _clicksdaily WHERE baniid=t.baniid GROUP BY baniid), "0") AS clicks';
$criteria->group = 't.baniid';
```

The query runs fine and get all the parameters back. the problem is that the impressions model doesnt have `click` attribute and it doesnt show as an attribute (so i can't use it in a widget)...

Any idea how can i assign another attribute from SQL query? (I added public $clicks, but it doesnt work).
Thanks.

Comment: You can create a `mysql view` and a `model` for it. I'm not sure if there is another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `public $clicks` seems to work for me.

In your model:

```
public $clicks;
public function scopes() {
    return array(
        'clicks' => array(
            'select' => 't.baniid,SUM(t.impression) AS impression, SUM(t.`unique`) AS `unique`, IFNULL((SELECT SUM(clicks) FROM _clicksdaily WHERE baniid=t.baniid), 0) AS clicks',
            'group ' => 'baniid',
        ),
    );
}
```

Then use it:

```
$firstModel = MyModel::model()->clicks()->find();
echo $firstModel->clicks;
```

Comment: it's working...shame on me i did CArrayDataProvider in one of my tests and forgot to change it back to CActive.